# Kidush Levana:  Does "aleichem shalom" count for a "shalom aleichem"?

Tags: kiddush-levanah, halacha, minhag

The minhag at kiddush levana is to wish shalom aleichem 3x.  It is prevalent to do so even if someone was wished shalom aleichem and he reciprocated back aleichem shalom.  Is there a reason that one needs to be the initiator of the blessing?

Comment: That is the Nusach of Kiddush Levana. I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Perhaps giving a blessing of peace is sufficient for the purpose of kiddush levana.  If 3 people preempted by wishing me shalom aleichem first and I had the opportunity to say aleichem shalom 3x, why doesn't that qualify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we just just finished saying a few verses with *curses* for our enemies, we then say Shalom Aleichem at Kiddush Levana to those around us, to highlight that we were not referring to them.

[The Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 426:2 (page 574 of vol. 4 of the Mishna Berura)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=185&hilite=) quoting the Tur, says that *"answering is like asking"*, and implies that you would **not** have to say Shalom Aleichem if you already responded Aleichem Shalom to 3 people.

Comment: That makes things easier, Danny.  (Thanks msh)

Comment: @YDK , Danny : It would only seem to count if they said it to you after you had already said "Tipol..." otherwise it's not serving it's purpose.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Perhaps, though I would suspect that there are multiple interpretations for saying shalom aleichem that are disconnected from tipol.

Comment: @DoubleAA, That's logical, though I wonder if the curses are the sole reasoning behind Shalom Aleichem.